# Why is an algebra not a $\sigma$-algebra by induction?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, induction, self-learning

I am studying probability theory by reading Sidney Resnick's "A Probability Path". On page 12 and 13, algebra and $\sigma$-algebra are defined. The only difference between the two is the third requirement.

- For algebra, it is required that $A, B\in \mathcal A \Rightarrow A\cup B\in \mathcal A.$ That is, algebra is closed under finite union;
- For $\sigma$-algebra, it is required that $B_i\in \mathcal B, i\geq 1 \Rightarrow \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\in\mathcal B$. That is, $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable union.

I find the definition for algebra confusing. If the union of $A$ and $B$ is in $\mathcal A$, then for any $C\in\mathcal A$ one has $(A\cup B)\cup C\in \mathcal A$ and so on. Then by induction, this extends to countable union. Why does induction NOT work in this case, please? Thank you!

Comment: The sum of finitely many rational numbers is rational. Hence the sum of infinitely many rational numbers is rational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this family of sets:
$$\mathcal A=\left\{\left(\frac1n, 1-\frac1n\right), n\in\mathbb N\right\}$$

If you take any two elements $A,B$ from $\mathcal A$, then $A\cup B$ is in $\mathcal A$. However, the union of *all* elements of $\mathcal A$ is *not* an element of $\mathcal A$.

Let $A_n = \left(\frac1n, 1-\frac1n\right)$. In a way, you can understand the problem this way: induction is used to prove statements about natural numbers. So, for example, the statement $$\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i\in\mathcal A$$
is a statement about the natural number $4$. With induction, you can prove that the statement
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\in\mathcal A$$
holds for all values of $n\in\mathbb N$. It is a statement in which, when you replace $n$ with some number, say $5$, you get a true statement about that particular number.

The statement you want to prove, however, is
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\mathcal A.$$
Unlike the previous statement, this is *not* a statement about the property of natural numbers. There are no natural numbers that appear in it which you can replace with actual numbers and get a correct statement.

Comment: First thank you for your response. Say n=3 and n=4, then $(1/3, 2/3)\cup(1/4, 3/4)$ is clearly in $\mathcal A$. Then why isn't the union of all elements of $\mathcal A$ which is $(0, 1)$ in $\mathcal A$?

Comment: indeed. But the union of ALL elements of $\mathcal A$ is NOT in $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Why isn't the union of all elements of $\mathcal A$ which is $(0, 1)$ in $\mathcal A$?

Comment: $(0,1)$ is not in $\mathcal A$. There is no $n\in\mathbb N$ for which $\left(\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n\right) = (0,1)$.

Comment: Because $1/n\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Thank both of you.

Comment: @5xum But what does this say about induction, please? Why doesn't induction work in this case, please?

Comment: Try and prove $(0,1)\in\mathcal A$ by induction. There's nothing to start with, the whole statement is not of the type to be proven by induction.

Comment: I added some more explanation on the intuition why induction does not work.

Answer (score 8):

There is a HUGE difference between being true for an arbitrarily large $n$, and being true an infinite set.

For a completely trivial example, you can prove that every subset of the natural numbers is bounded using the same logic, which is clearly nonsense.

To see a basic non-trivial example, consider closed sets in $\Bbb R$. By induction finite unions of closed sets are closed, but it should not be too difficult to come up with a counterexample for the countably infinite case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But what does this say about induction? Why does NOT induction work here, please?

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed prove by induction, that in an algebra $\mathcal A$ you have
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \in \mathcal A
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $A_i\in\mathcal A$.

So induction gives you that every finite union, no matter how many sets involved, is again an element of the algebra. Still $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is not a union of this kind!

Answer (score 2):

Why does induction not work here? Well, why does it work in the finite case?
Suppose it did not work. Then, we have a set $A$ of indices for which the proposition does not hold (in the case at hand: when $k \in A$, $\cup_{i=1}^k B_i\not\in\mathcal B$ in general).

By the well-ordering principle, $A$ has a least element (call it $\ell$). Thus, the proposition does hold for $n=\ell-1$. Proof by induction means you show that if the proposition holds for $n$, it must also hold for $n+1$. Therefore, if it holds for $\ell-1$, it holds for $\ell$ as well. But this is a contradiction, since $\ell$ is the first value of $n$ where the proposition does *not* hold.

This proves induction (in the finite case). If we try the same proof for the countably infinite case, we first have to define $A$ in a sensible way. This cannot be done via natural numbers since $\infty$ is not a natural number, so $A$ would be empty.
One can use the concept of ordinal numbers, but $\omega_0$ does not have a predecessor (i.e. $\infty-1$ does not exist), so the usual step from $n$ to $n+1$ is not sufficient to reach a contradiction to $\omega_0$ being the first element of $A$.

The method of proof by induction can be extended to work in this case also (*transfinite induction*), but extra work is required to deal with *limit ordinals* (i.e. those that do not have a predecessor).

Needless to say, this extra work would fail in the case at hand since there are counter-examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are many counter examples, for example consider the set $M:= \{ A\in\mathbb{R}|A\text{ is closed}\}$, clearly $A\in M,B \in M \implies A\cup B \in M$, but consider $A_i:=[0,1-\frac{1}{i}]$, then $A_i \in M \forall i\in \mathbb{N}$, but $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i=[0,1) \notin M$.

Answer (score 0):

The induction step allows you to go from $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\in\mathcal{B}$ to $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\cup B_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B_i\in\mathcal{B}.$$
The step you would need would be of the form $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty-1}B_i\cup B_\infty=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\in\mathcal{B},$$ which is a nonsense expression.